# How can I use the TaggedDocument function (Gensim \ Doc2Vec) via Reticulate in R?

Tags: r, gensim, doc2vec, reticulate

I am trying to run Python's gensim package in R environment via reticulate. More specifically, I am trying to build a doc2vec model, for which a corpus of tokens and tags needs to be prepared.

The TaggedDocument function is where I am having problems. Here's an example in python of what I am trying to reproduce in R:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

data = ["this is the first sentence",
        "running doc2vec via reticulate",
        "r and python bff forever",
        "this aint working"]

tags = ["a","b","a","c"]

corpus = pd.DataFrame({"sentences": data, "labels": tags})

tagged_data = corpus.apply(
    lambda r: TaggedDocument(words=word_tokenize(r['sentences']), tags=[r.labels]), axis=1)
```

This results in an output of this kind:

```
0       ([this, is, the, first, sentence], [a])
1    ([running, doc2vec, via, reticulate], [b])
2         ([r, and, python, bff, forever], [a])
3                  ([this, aint, working], [c])
dtype: object
```

which can be used to build a vocabulary and train a doc2vec model.

How can I get to the same result in R (possibly without loops)?

```
library(reticulate)

gensim <- import("gensim") 
Doc2Vec <- gensim$models$Doc2Vec 
TaggedDocument <- gensim$models$doc2vec$TaggedDocument


sentences <- c("this is the first sentence",
        "running doc2vec via reticulate",
        "r and python bff forever",
        "this aint working")

labels <- c("a","b","c","a")
```

Thanks in advance!

*** EDIT ***

I have been trying an even simpler setting:

```
library(reticulate)

gensim <- import("gensim") 
Doc2Vec <- gensim$models$Doc2Vec 
TaggedDocument <- gensim$models$doc2vec$TaggedDocument


sentences <- c("this is the first sentence")
tags <- c("a")

df <- data.frame (tokens= sentences, labels = tags)

tagged_docs <- TaggedDocument(words = df$tokens, tags = df$labels)
```

but I keep receiving the same error message:

> Blockquote
>   Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
>     AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'words' - Detailed traceback: 
>     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\doc2vec.py", line 1184, in build_vocab
>       progress_per=progress_per, trim_rule=trim_rule
>     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\doc2vec.py", line 1381, in scan_vocab
>       total_words, corpus_count = self._scan_vocab(documents, docvecs, progress_per, trim_rule)
>     File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\doc2vec.py", line 1310, in _scan_vocab
>       if isinstance(document.words, string_types):

**---**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I did not get your error, I am on reticulate_1.16 and gensim 3.8.3, ntlk 3.4.4. Might be easier if you call a python script and pass it back to R.

This would be your python script:

```
py_script = c("", "import pandas as pd", "import numpy as np", "from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument", 
"from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize", "", "tagged_data = r.df_py.apply(", 
"    lambda r: TaggedDocument(words=word_tokenize(r['sentences']), tags=[r.labels]), axis=1)", 
"") 

cat(py_script,sep="\n")

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

tagged_data = r.df_py.apply(
    lambda r: TaggedDocument(words=word_tokenize(r['sentences']), tags=[r.labels]), axis=1)

writeLines(py_script,"run.py")
```

Then in R:

```
library(reticulate)

sentences <- c("this is the first sentence",
        "running doc2vec via reticulate",
        "r and python bff forever",
        "this aint working")

labels <- c("a","b","c","a")
df = data.frame(sentences,labels)

df_py <- r_to_py(df)
py_run_file("run.py")
py$tagged_data
$`0`
TaggedDocument(['this', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'sentence'], ['a'])

$`1`
TaggedDocument(['running', 'doc2vec', 'via', 'reticulate'], ['b'])

$`2`
TaggedDocument(['r', 'and', 'python', 'bff', 'forever'], ['c'])

$`3`
TaggedDocument(['this', 'aint', 'working'], ['a'])
```